# VOIP push not receiving in live app iOS nor in the release build

Tags: ios, twilio, voip

I have a live app which was working fine and the work flow is

someone click on call from web -> voip push is sent to iOS device -> it shows callkit ringing ui-> user accept the call .

But now nor the live app neither the new release build getting voip push . and not incoming call is showing in phone.

i tried to send the voip push from Pusher but its is giving me error for "Unable to read: Read connection closed
"

Voip push certificate is valid till October 21.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been fixed as the implementation on backend is 6 years old and are using push notifications with the legacy binary protocol,Since apple removed that as per the [link](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=c88acm2b#:%7E:text=The%20HTTP%2F2%2Dbased%20Apple,%2C%20and%20per%2Dnotification%20feedback.&text=APNs%20will%20no%20longer%20support%20the%20legacy%20binary%20protocol%20after%20this%20date.)

So we have updated according to new implementation and get it worked